# How do we pick the contact point for distributed contact forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, statics

Suppose I have two structures of three blocks of the same shape with mass 1.0.

The structures are in the exact same poses.

I have drawn two sets of forces that can satisfy static equilibrium.

[image]

However, which set of forces is correct?

The one on the right seems more intuitive to me because of the symmetry of the problem, but the one on the left doesn't seem to violate any physical rules either.

More generally - for a distributed load from gravity, we have the center of gravity as the correct point of application for the resultant force.

But the supporting blocks in my scenario are technically applying a "distributed contact load" upwards on the topmost block. How do we find the point of application for the resultant contact forces applied from each bottom block to the top block?

Comment: This setup is *statically indeterminate*, meaning that both are "correct" if we are not given further information on material properties (In reality, there would be a distribution of forces). I think another example would be a beam supported at three or more points.

Answer (score 0):

If the blocks are horizontal and the blocks have uniform density then the contact forces must be symmetrically distributed across the lower face of the upper block, otherwise they will create a turning moment on the upper block.

In general, the contact forces must not create a turning moment about the upper block's centre of gravity, so you can replace the contact forces with a single force passing through the upper block's COG.

Answer (score 0):

The examples above describe a plane-plane contact between the boxes and the floor, or box to box.

[image: fig1]

For this type of contact the load is pushed to the edges and furthermore the loads at the edges is pushed to the corners.

In the diagram above left, the general idea of how contact pressure is distributed for these kind of flat contacts is shown with the red shaded region.

On the right, is the the common idealization for this situation using *two* forces are ends of the contacts.

The same idealization is valid for all box-to-floor contacts, as well as box-to-box.

I am showing this below in a FBD schematic with the objects separated to discern on which body are the forces applied. Included are the forces of gravity also.

[image: fig2]

Now as far as solving for the forces, what you have here is a statically indeterminant situation, but also you have symmetry which provides enough conditions to make this problem solvable.

[image: fig3]

By labeling the forces the symmetry means that (1)=(4) and (2)=(3) and (5)=(6).

But note because the forces from the box above do not act on the center of the boxes below, the forces (1) and (2) **are not equal** to each other.

You need to do a force/torque balance to get the estimated load distribution.